# How do I see the actual XML generated by PHP SOAP Client Class?

Tags: php, xml, soap

Consider this example SOAP Client script:

```
$SOAP = new SoapClient($WDSL); // Create a SOAP Client from a WSDL

// Build an array of data to send in the request.
$Data = array('Something'=>'Some String','SomeNumber'=>22); 

$Response = $SOAP->DoRemoteFunction($Data); // Send the request.
```

On the last line, PHP takes the arguments from the array you specified, and, using the WSDL, builds the XML request to send, then sends it.

How can I get PHP to show me the actual XML it's built?

I'm troubleshooting an application and need to see the actual XML of the request.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Use [`getLastRequest`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php). It returns the XML sent in the last SOAP request.

```
echo "REQUEST:\n" . $SOAP->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
```

And remember, this method works only if the SoapClient object was created with the `trace` option set to `TRUE`. Therefore, when creating the object, use this code:

```
$SOAP = new SoapClient($WDSL, array('trace' => 1));
```

Comment: Still useful after 6 years

Comment: Similarly, if you want to get the response XML, use [`SoapClient::__getLastResponse()`](https://www.php.net/soapclient.getlastresponse). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7147677/1657502).

Comment: @KasunRajapaksha still useful after (nearly) 12 years :)

Answer (score 24):

```
$SOAP = new SoapClient($WSDL, array('trace' => true));

$Response = $SOAP->DoRemoteFunction($Data);

echo "REQUEST:\n" . htmlentities($SOAP->__getLastRequest()) . "\n";
```

This will not only print the last request but also make the XML tags visible in the browser.

Comment: Yeah, this my GOTCHA! I foolishly forgot that Chrome simply drops all the XML it finds, so it didn't matter that a <pre> was wrapping the response and thought that SoapClient was refusing to display the last request. A simple view:source corrected that and htmlspecialchars() made it all better.

Answer (score 20):

If you'd like to view the request without actually making a connection, you can override SoapClient's `__doRequest` method to return the XML:

```
class DummySoapClient extends SoapClient {
    function __construct($wsdl, $options) {
        parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
    }
    function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) {
        return $request;
    }
}
$SOAP = new DummySoapClient('http://example.com/?wsdl', array('trace' => true));
echo $SOAP->GetRequestDetail($params);
```

Answer (score 11):

Extending Quinn's answer, you can also just log the request before you perform the request.

```
class SoapClientDebug extends SoapClient
{

public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
{
    error_log("REQUEST:\n" .$request . "\n");
    error_log("LOCATION:\n" .$location . "\n");
    error_log("ACTION:\n" .$action . "\n");
    error_log("VERSION:\n" .$version . "\n");
    error_log("ONE WAY:\n" .$one_way . "\n");

    return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to enable tracing when you create your SoapClient. Like so:

```
$SOAP = new SoapClient($WSDL, array('trace' => true));

$Data = array('Something'=>'Some String','SomeNumber'=>22);
```

Then call the __getLastRequest method after you've made a service call to see the XML.

```
$Response = $SOAP->DoRemoteFunction($Data);
echo $SOAP->__getLastRequest();
```

This will output the request XML.

More reading: http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php

Comment: I have tried to get XML values, my code: https://justpaste.it/3rwzs and return values as an object, how can i get my values as XML? thank you @Ezequiel Muns

Comment: @Gem you can use  `echo htmlentities($SOAP->__getLastRequest());` to see it as XML

Answer (score 3):

if you are running the client locally, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a great implementation agnostic way of looking at the messages on the wire.

If you are running it remotely then you could use something like [Apache TCPMON](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon) [Standalone](http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/tcpmontutorial.html) or through [eclipse](http://charithaka.blogspot.com/2008/08/how-to-use-tcpmon-inside-eclipse.html)*

*just linking to the first hit from [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=eclipse+tcpmon)

Comment: Fiddler is useless if SOAP service is behind https as `php_openssl.dll` cannot be traced as it's not using wininet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with [Quinn Comendant's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277303/quinn-comendant) answer, that `$request` from `__doRequest()` will then be processed by `__call()` and the user will see an array of parameters instead of real xml request. To prevent this, such workaround can be used:

```
class DummySoapClient extends SoapClient {
    function __construct($wsdl, $options) {
        parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
    }

    function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) {
        throw new Exception($request);
    }

    function __call($function_name, $arguments)
    {
        try {
            parent::__call($function_name, $arguments);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Option `trace` is not necessary here, because we do not call `__getLastRequest()` or other relevant functions.