# Get received XML from PHP SOAP Server

Tags: php, soap, symfony

I'm using the build-in SOAP-Server within a symfony2 application and beside handling the StdClass-Object, I would need to read the complete xml received for debugging and logging. Is there a way to simply catch the transferred xml? It should be somewhere in the request header, but I simply can't find it there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I see the actual XML generated by PHP SOAP Client Class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572414/how-do-i-see-the-actual-xml-generated-by-php-soap-client-class)

Comment: And for the SOAP server: http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapserver.handle.php

Comment: I don't see how the handle function helps me in recieving the raw xml?

Comment: quoting: *`soap_request`- The SOAP request. If this argument is omitted, the request is assumed to be in the raw POST data of the HTTP request.*

Comment: Ok, so you suggest I read the xml direkt from the raw http post? What is strange is, that the soap server is working but I cannot get any POST or GET data; Both seems to be empty. Do you have any idea where the xml request can be stored? I tried all variables but I'm not able to catch any relevant data.

Comment: Well, they should be in soap_request or $_POST. Try to step through the execution process with XDebug if they are not in there to find them

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing and finally found it. Hope this helps you or someone else.

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

The `$postdata` variable will have the raw XML. Found through the following two links:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php

http://php.net/manual/en/soapserver.soapserver.php

Comment: AWESOME! this is exactly what I really need too!

Comment: Thank you! That is what I need!

Comment: Superb answer, very helpful to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The raw XML transmitted in a SOAP envelope should be in the POST body. In a Symfony application, you can get the body of the POST request by creating a *Request* object and calling its *getContents()* method.

### Within a Controller

You can get request contents easily in the controller, like so:

```
// src/MyProject/MyBundle/Controller/MyController.php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

...

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$soapEnvelope = $request->getContents();
```

### Within a Service

Best practice (for Symfony 2.4+) is to inject a RequestStack into your service class within the service container. You can do it as a constructor argument to your service class, by invoking a setter method, etc. Here's a quick example using injection via the constructor.

In your service container:

```
// src/MyProject/MyBundle/Resources/config/services.xml
<service id="my.service" class="MyServiceClass">
    <argument type="service" id="request_stack" />
</service>
```

Then in your service class:

```
// src/MyProject/MyBundle/Service/MyService.php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

....

class MyServiceClass
{
    /**
     * @var RequestStack $rs
     */
    private $requestStack;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param RequestStack $requestStack
     */
    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    /**
     * Some method where you need to access the raw SOAP xml
     */
    public function myMethod()
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        $soapEnvelope = $request->getContents();
    }
}
```

Reference documentation:

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack