# Php Soap, Dump Result as XMl FILE?

Tags: php, xml, file, soap, save

I got a SOAP (normal php client) Result
from my request
I want to save the result as a XML file ? But how ?

```
   $result = $client->__soapCall('MYwebServices',array($params));

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

    $fp = fopen("out.xml","w");
    fwrite($fp,$xml);
    fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the XML returned by the web service, you should use [`SoapClient::__getLastResponse()`](http://php.net/soapclient.getlastresponse) (along with the `trace` option).

```
$client = new SoapClient(..., array('trace' => 1));

// Do your __soapCall here

$xml = $client->__getLastResponse();

// Work with the XML string here
```

Comment: Similarly, if you want to get the request XML, use [`SoapClient::__getLastRequest()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3572445/1657502).

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml->asXML("out.xml");
```

[`SimpleXMLElement::asXML` reference](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/simplexmlelement.asxml.php)

Comment: Confirmed that the above does not work ? could be i got a few namespaces in result ?

Comment: Sorry, don't get you. You might need to chec if you SOAP request successful: `is_soap_fault($result)`. Here's manual on [is_soap_fault](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.is-soap-fault.php)

Answer (score 0):

Does the code above not do it, if not try:

```
$result = $client->__soapCall('MYwebServices',array($params));

    $xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load($result);
$xml->save("out.xml");
```

This might be broken if the return is not xml or the xml is improperly formatted, in which case try this:

```
$result = $client->__soapCall('MYwebServices',array($params));
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);//load if improperly formatted
        $xml = new DOMDocument();
    if ($xml->load($result))
    {
        $xml->save("out.xml");
    }
    else {
        echo "The return data was not xml";
    }
```